# Why can we use 'new' keyword to get reference of a static inner class within a non-static outer class?

Tags: java, class, static, linked-list, instance

As you can see from the following code, we write `RemoveDups_1.LinkedList linkedList = new RemoveDups_1.LinkedList();`  to get an instance of static class LinkedList within a non-static class RemoveDups_1. As this is a static class, why do we need to use new keyword for getting the instance of class `LinkedList`?

```
import java.util.*;

public class RemoveDups_1{
    public static class LinkedList{

        static int i = 5;

        class Node{
            int data;
            Node next;

            public Node(int data){
                this.data = data;
            }
        }

        Node head;

        public void appendToTail(int data){
            if(head == null){
                head = new Node(data);
            }
            else{
                Node node_to_append = new Node(data);
                Node node = head;
                while(node.next != null){
                    node = node.next;
                }
                node.next = node_to_append;
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){

        RemoveDups_1 removeDups_1 = new RemoveDups_1();
        RemoveDups_1.LinkedList linkedList = new RemoveDups_1.LinkedList();     
        RemoveDups_1.LinkedList.Node node;
        node = linkedList.new Node(3);

        System.out.println(RemoveDups_1.LinkedList.i);

    }
}
```

Comment: just wonder what makes you think you do not need to `new` for a new instance of static inner class (or even any class)?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static Inner class" in Java, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList is nested class, you need it to be static in order to instantiate it without the need of creating instance of its outer class

Comment: No, it's *not* an inner class - it's a nested class. It would only be an inner class if it didn't have the static modifier.

Answer (score 0):

"why do we need to use `new` keyword for getting the instance of class LinkedList?"

Because that's how you allocate memory for an instance of a class, regardless of whether it's a top-level or nested class, static or inner. The difference between a static nested class member and an inner class member is that the former is not associated with an instance of the outer class, and the latter is.

Comment: If an instance of RemoveDups_1 is created, does not it automatically create an instance of LinkedList as it is a static member of RemoveDups_1? Isn't that what 'static' means, that static variables are created when class is initialized? If this would be the scenario, why do we need to use 'new' keyword to get an instance of 'LinkedList' class within RemoveDups_1? Doesn't 'new' keyword create a new instance which would be contradictory here as LinkedList is a static class?

Comment: For consideration, how can following method be a part of RemoveDups_1 class where it creates 2 new instances of LinkedList. 1. list_lesser and 2. list_greater_or_equal. Isn't there supposed to be only 1 LinkedList as it is static? 
`public static void run(){

                LinkedList list_lesser = new LinkedList();
  LinkedList list_greater_or_equal = new LinkedList();  

}`

Comment: No, an instance of `LinkedList` is _not_ automatically created! There's no reference to it as a class member. Only the type is defined. To get an instance uses the `new` keyword, as explained.

Comment: You can create multiple instances of a class. Read the Java Tutorial.